# Oxyplot: Candle overlap each candle

Tags: c#, charts, oxyplot, candlestick-chart

When reducing charts the candle begins to overlap another candle.

For example

[image]

[image]

[image]

Axises

```
DateTimeAxis timeSPanAxis1 = new DateTimeAxis()
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                MinorIntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto,
                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MajorGridlineColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(44, 44, 44),
                TicklineColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(82, 82, 82)
            };
            PlotModel.Axes.Add(timeSPanAxis1);

            LinearAxis linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis()
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Right,

                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot,
                MajorGridlineColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(44, 44, 44),
                TicklineColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(82, 82, 82)
            };
            PlotModel.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
```

and candle stick series

```
CandleStickSeries candle = new CandleStickSeries()
            {
                Color = OxyColors.Black,
                IncreasingColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(0,197,49),
                DecreasingColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(255,95,95),
                DataFieldX = "Time",
                DataFieldHigh = "H",
                DataFieldLow = "L",
                DataFieldClose = "C",
                DataFieldOpen = "O",
                TrackerFormatString = "Date: {2}\nOpen: {5:0.00000}\nHigh: {3:0.00000}\nLow: {4:0.00000}\nClose: {6:0.00000}",

            };
```

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: I think it´s probably not possible to fully avoid an overlap of the strokes, when you scale down the chart. You can try to set your `candleSeries.StrokeThickness = 0.5;` to minimum to minimize the overlapping.

Comment: @JohnnyQ thanks for comment, yes, StrokeThickness a little help. I note that in the first problem with a candle doji (when open=close)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue concerning the doji candles.

The pull request can be found on
[GitHub](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/pull/1246).